# How do you convert the SqlDateTime value to .Net::DateTime

Tags: c#, sql, datetime

Tried searching everywhere and no go.

The approach so far is `DateTime dt = (DateTime)sqlparam.Value;`. Which I can imagine can go wrong on different configurations, different SQL regional settings, different PC regional settings and so on. But then again, parsing value off SQL datetime string is even crazier idea.

Is there a working solution for this, it's .NET, there should be one, right?

Comment: Yes, the binary representation is a DATETIME, and I don't think it's binary compatible to Net::DateTime, also, the debugger shows some weird time string and I am not sure the internal conversion is done correctly, not through some DateTime::TryParse((sqlparam as object).ToString());

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see what's wrong with explicitly casting it, that's how I'd do it.

If your problems are being caused by "different configurations, different SQL regional settings, different PC regional settings" then using a different conversion method won't help.

However, you might like to look at this new data type in SQL Server 2008:
[DateTimeOffset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630289.aspx)

Comment: It does seem to work, I'll hope it's alright, although I am not sure, as .NET is way to far from the metal, no idea what it does underneath.

Answer (score 17):

The `SqlDateTime` class has a property `Value` which is already of type `DateTime`. Why would any conversion be necessary? Just use the `Value` directly.

Comment: But the parameter is `SqlParameter("@param", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime);` not `SqlDateTime`

Answer (score 6):

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    // Taken from MySQL: SELECT CURTIME()
    //                   SELECT TIME(...)
    string mySqlTime = "23:50:26";
    DateTime time = DateTime.Parse(mySqlTime);

    // Taken from MySQL: SELECT TIMESTAMP(...)
    string mySqlTimestamp = "2003-12-31 00:00:00";
    time = DateTime.Parse(mySqlTimestamp);
    Console.WriteLine(time);

    // Taken from MySQL: SELECT CURDATE()
    //                   SELECT DATE(...)
    string mySqlDate = "2008-06-13";
    time = DateTime.Parse(mySqlDate);
    Console.WriteLine(time);
    }
}
```

Comment: The dates 2008-20-10 == 2008-10-20 == 10-20-2008 == 20-10-2008 == etc. That's what seems to be the problem, especially if I have to deploy the application over PCs with different regional options.

Answer (score 2):

Just cast it to DateTime. 
 If it's nullable, cast it to Nullable, which can also be written as "DateTime?".

```
DateTime? value = (DateTime?)resultSet["myDateColumn"];
```

look at the [SqlDateTime Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqldatetime.aspx)

it has a Parse methods you can Parse you string into the SqlDateTime after cast into DateTime

Answer (score 0):

Try using `SqlDateTime.op_Explicit()` [Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exzwfa5y%28v=VS.100%29.aspx AND http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa326475%28v=vs.71%29.aspx
Also,

Try this `DateTime orderDate = Convert.ToDateTime(sqlparam.Value.ToString());`